# Webpack using plugins array

Tags: javascript, webpack

We have created webpack config. We want to generate multiple html pages using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. So I was trying to genrate mutltiple pages using array of new HTMLWebpackPlugin() like this :

```
var HtmlWebpackPluginArray = [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: "TV Grid_1---",
    template: APP_DIR + '/index.template.ejs',
    filename: "grid_1.html",
    minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
    }
}), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: "TV Grid_2---",
    template: APP_DIR + '/index.template.ejs',
    filename: "grid_2.html",
    minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
    }
})];
```

Webpack config :

```
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(DIST_PATH),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'styles.[chunkhash].css',
        // disable: false,
        allChunks: true
    }),
    // new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        filename: 'vendor.[chunkhash].js'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'manifest'
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
  HtmlWebpackPluginArray,
]
```

I get following error :

```
TypeError: arguments[i].apply is not a function
```

Can we use array of plugins ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we use array of plugins ?

Yes, but your code is currently producing an array of plugins with another array of plugins inside it:

```
// this (your code with plugin config omitted):
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(…),
    new ExtractTextPlugin(…),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(…),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(…),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(…),
    HtmlWebpackPluginArray
]

// results in:
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(…),
    new ExtractTextPlugin(…),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(…),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(…),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(…),
    [
         new HtmlWebpackPlugin(…),
         new HtmlWebpackPlugin(…)
    ];
]
```

This won't work, because Webpack tries to call `.apply()` on an array. The error message you posted comes from that.

You need to merge the arrays rather than put one into another:

```
// this:
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(…),
    new ExtractTextPlugin(…),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(…),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(…),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(…),
].concat(HtmlWebpackPluginArray)

// results in:
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(…),
    new ExtractTextPlugin(…),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(…),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(…),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(…),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(…),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(…)
]
// …which is valid config and will work
```

The [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method merges two (or more) arrays into a new one without altering the original arrays. Another way would be to use an array spread like so:

```
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(…),
    new ExtractTextPlugin(…),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(…),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(…),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(…),
    ...HtmlWebpackPluginArray
] // -> same result as from .concat above
```

Btw. if you plan to update to Webpack 4, you can simplify the plugin config a bit – there's no `CommonsChunkPlugin` anymore, and chunks are configured in webpack's config object directly.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation I understood now :).